# Links in a swf file

Tags: c#, flash

I have a worldmap.swf, were I have incorporated a small logo in any continent, that clicking in each one it gives me only the countries of that specific continent, where also incorporated another logo in each country.
I need to create a link in every country’s logo, which must open a different web site.
Example: one logo in North America continent, which opens UDSA and Canada. 
By clicking the logo of USA must open a web site relating to USA,  the logo of Canada, must open a website relating to Canada, and so on
Can somebody help me here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [flash.net.navigateToURL()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()).

Store logos in an array and their **corresponding** urls in another one. Assign same click handler to all the logos. Within the handler, find the index of clicked logo (`event.target`) in the logos array and get the corresponding url using that index and navigate to that url.

```
var logos:Array = [usLogo, ukLogo, asiaLogo, /*etc*/];
var urls:Array = ["usa.html", "uk.html", "asia.html", /*etc*/];

for each(var logo:MovieClip in logos)
  logo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoWebsite);

function gotoWebsite(event:Event):void
{
  var index:Number = logos.indexOf(event.target);
  var url:String = urls[index];
  navigateToURL(url);
}
```

Comment: Hi there.

Thank you very much for your help.
Never the less I'm a newbie in flash.
There is a possibility of send you the file and you do one link and give instructions step by step how to he others?

I would be very much gratefully
you can find me at agimoura@hotmail.com if you whish.

Comment: Didn't this code work? What was the error? Set `gotoWebsite` as the `click` event listener of all the logos (or the links therein). Now within the function find the clicked one using the `event.target` property and use the corresponding url.

Comment: I've update the code using arrays (which I think is simpler). Ask your doubts here - that's what SO is for - mailing them to me is not okay.

Comment: I cannot find where must i addthe code. I open the fla with the flash. I have several layers and I do not know yet how to work much abou it. I cannot find the code that you wre talking about. In wich laer must i set the code? That's the reason that i'm asking if you can do one and tell me how must i do it. thanks

Comment: I work on Flex Builder (and not CS3), so I cannot even open an fla to begin with. Search for some CS3 tutorials to learn how to add event listeners to objects in an fla and where to add code.